# LocalDate или Date

Tags: java, дата, java-8

Сколько бы примеров и полей с датами на Java я не видел, всегда (или почти всегда) используют класс `Date`. При этом, я думаю, всем известно, что класс `Date` сам по себе плохой: он не потокобезопасен и представляет собой не то, что указано в его названии (мы получаем дата-время вместо даты). В это же время классы `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` и `LocalTime` полностью покрывают эти недостатки и вообще более удобны в использовании. Возникает вопрос, почему тогда все еще люди (и не абы какие, а даже в некоторых оф. документациях так) используют класс `Date`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Class Date
...
Since:
    JDK1.0
```

vs

```
Class LocalDate
...
Since:
    1.8
```

Ну это основная причина, т.е. куча кода написана используя `java.util.Date` и не будет никогда переписана. До появления в 8 версии `java.time` также во всю использовалась библиотека [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html). Дело привычки и истории. На данный момент, естественно если есть выбор и нет необходимости поддерживать legacy-код, лучше использовать `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` и т.д.